# Python & Simpy: simulate limited throughput and network congestion

Tags: python, simpy

I'm using `simpy` in my implementation of a discrete network simulator. However, for now, my servers (my own class) process any number of received packets. But in real networks, each server has certain maximum throughput capacity, which I would like to add as well in my simulator. Is there a way in `simpy` to simulate the servers having limited capacity, and hence see at what traffic rate the congestion starts?

Answer (score 1):

Simpy has the [`Resource`](https://simpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topical_guides/resources.html) class for simulating shared/limited resources. Different types of resources are available for different types of needs.

In your case, if your dealing with TCP connections, you can have a `Resource` in each server, and machines trying to send messages to the server first need to "acquire" that resource to establish a connection (e.g. simulate a maximum number of connections). This is somewhat similar to the [Carwash](https://simpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/carwash.html) example in simpy documentation.

If your dealing with UDP packets, you might want to look into [`Store`](https://simpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topical_guides/resources.html#res-type-store) resource, and make it so that each packet sent to the server goes to that server's Store before being processed. If the Store is full, the packet is not delivered.